# How to make your program defensive against the situation of overflow by using “limits” header?

Tags: c++

This is the code I have made, Please tell me how to make it defensive against the situation of overflow by using "limits" header.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
#define MAX 100
int main()
{
    cout<<"decimal to binary conversion"<<endl;
    bool binary[MAX];



    int decimal_num,i;
    cout<<"decimal number:"<<endl;
    cin>>decimal_num;

    for(i=0; (decimal_num/2)!=0; ++i)
    {
        binary[i]=decimal_num%2;
        decimal_num/=2;

    }
    binary[i]=decimal_num;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Binary equivalent :"<<endl;
    for(i; i>=0;--i)
    {
        cout<<binary[i];
    }
    cout<<endl<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post your code directly as text instead of posting an image of your code.

Answer (score 1):

There seems no point of causing overflow other than the input.

Give up using `cin` to read an integer directly and check for the input while reading digit by digit.

Define this function

```
// read an non-negative integer from stdin
int read_num(void) {
    char input;
    int ret = -1;
    while (cin>>input) {
        if ('0' <= input && input <= '9') {
            int n = input - '0'; // the digit read
            if (ret < 0) ret = 0;
            // check if multiplying 10 will cause an overflow
            if (INT_MAX / 10 < ret) {
                cout << "overflow detected!" << endl;
                return -1;
            }
            ret *= 10;
            // check if adding n will cause an overflow
            if (INT_MAX - n < ret) {
                 cout << "overflow detected!" << endl;
                 return -1;
            }
            ret += n;
        } else break;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

before defining `main()` and change

```
cin>>decimal_num;
```

to

```
decimal_num = read_num();
if (decimal_num < 0) return 1;
```

Note that type `bool` is not for storeing integer and I think you should use `int` type for `binary`.

Comment: This is an assignment I have been given, and the conditions require me to use bool array for binary and to use limits.h to make it defensive against overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this to get the size of an int as measured in bits:

```
static const unsigned MAX = 1 + std::numeric_limits<int>::digits;
```

I'm not very fond of the *(+1)* part, so this definition should be neater:

```
static const unsigned MAX = sizeof(int) * std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::digits;
```